# springmvc handle the json request

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I understand if I use springMVC and pass a json object to the controller, it will try to bind the json object to the controller pararmenter, but how to handle the binding error? I use something like this but seems not userful.

```
public String save(@RequestBody @Valid SomeList list, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasError()){
        System.out.println(result);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can return the same view that submitted the data. If you have `<form:error>` tags there, they will be displayed (because of the binding information).

But this is most certainly an ajax call, so what you can do is set a specific response status in the if body:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

and then look for that status code (406) in the ajax response handler. If you want precise validation information, you can try serializing the binding result itself as a response.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println will do next to nothing.  Basically what it's saying is output the binding result to the server jvm std out.

Since you're returning a String, I'm going to assume you're returning a view name, so you might want to redirect the user to an error page.